# Why does the onChange event trigger every time I change the year in a date field in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, datepicker

The onChange event trigger every time I change the year in a date field in chrome? If I already entered a date and change the day or month it triggers too. I would expect this to only trigger when I leave the input field.

I didn't expect onChange to trigger unless the date field loses focus. Any idea what is going on here?

W3School documentation on onChange: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```js
let date = document.getElementById('date');
date.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('change event triggered'));
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" />
```

Comment: FYI w3schools are _nothing_ to do with W3C. They purposely chose that name to mislead people.

Comment: @turnip okay, edited to w3School in case it would cause confusion :).

Comment: The event fires once when you set an inital date and then fires again any time you change the date. That seems to make perfect sense to me. If you only want one event, you could use `blur` or `focusout`.

Comment: @Turnip It is a different behaviour from the other input fields, which only trigger once the focus leaves the input field. If I actually use the datepicker it works fine. But when I type a date it will run with a year of 0001. This is a problem because I want to submit data to my server after the field has been edited.

Comment: Is same behavior as number input but differs from text input. Just have to realize that and react accordingly in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked page says:

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been
>   changed.

Which would imply that this is correct behaviour.

It sounds like you're looking for `onblur`, which fires when an element loses focus. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Comment: The confusing part (for me) seems to happen when I type a character in yyyy. It automatically converts to 0001 and triggers the event because the date is suddenly valid. I personally would't expect that to happen until I typed the full date. But as you said I am better of using unblur :)

Comment: Based on MDN webdoc, the input type date field supprts only "input" and "onchange" events. "onblur" event is not supported. I tried. Under crome this input is really hard to handle. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date